# Android Webkit in background

Tags: android, webkit

Is there a way to get `webkit` running in the background , or even small enough for the user not to know that the `webkit browser` is running?

Basically i want to use this to have java and `javascript` integration while using the `android UI`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it invisible.

Comment: If I make it invisible, can i still load data in it?

Comment: Works for me. What I have done, for example, is set up a full-screen invisible WebView, had it start loading some page, and then have an animated ImageView as a progress indicator. When the page is done loading, I stop the animation, make the ImageView invisible, then make the WebView visible. Note that this is a heavyweight solution for whatever problem you're trying to solve -- WebView will use a fair chunk of RAM. If you can find a pure-Java solution to your problem, that would be better.

Comment: Thanks man, hmm ill try to come up with an alternative solution. Thanks though!